# Create custom time intervals for plotting time series in r

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, posixct

**I have Timestamp data in the form: "YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS". I want to be able to create custom bins of 6 hours each for plotting. How do i create these intervals in r? Please see sample data below:**

```
2021-05-25 14:56:45.19,
2021-05-25 14:56:47.50,
2021-05-25 14:56:48.28,
2021-05-25 14:56:49.42,
2021-05-25 14:57:01.64,
2021-05-25 14:57:19.46,
2021-05-25 14:57:21.87,
2021-05-25 14:57:22.65,
2021-05-25 14:57:23.79,
2021-05-25 15:04:46.01,
2021-05-25 15:04:46.38,
2021-05-25 15:04:51.21,
2021-05-25 15:04:51.58,
2021-05-25 14:57:53.83,
2021-05-25 14:57:57.40,
2021-05-25 14:57:58.17,
2021-05-25 14:57:59.31,
2021-05-25 14:58:01.65,
2021-05-25 14:58:29.34,
2021-05-25 14:58:31.66,
2021-05-25 14:58:32.17,
2021-05-25 14:58:32.76,
2021-05-25 14:58:33.88,
2021-05-25 14:59:01.66,
2021-05-25 14:59:03.93,
2021-05-25 14:59:06.11,
2021-05-25 14:59:06.86,
2021-05-25 14:59:07.99,
2021-05-25 14:59:31.67,
2021-05-25 14:59:40.04,
2021-05-25 14:59:41.94,
2021-05-25 15:00:14.97,
2021-05-25 14:59:38.03,
2021-05-25 14:59:40.80,
2021-05-25 15:00:01.67,
2021-05-25 15:00:11.98,
2021-05-25 15:00:15.74,
2021-05-25 15:00:31.67,
2021-05-25 15:00:46.91,
2021-05-25 15:00:50.11,
2021-05-25 15:01:01.68,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.09,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.09,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.21,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.21,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.21,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.21,
2021-05-25 15:06:17.58,
2021-05-25 15:06:18.61,
2021-05-25 15:06:18.98,
2021-05-25 13:25:50.14,
2021-05-25 13:25:50.14,
2021-05-25 13:25:50.15,
2021-05-25 13:25:50.15,
2021-05-25 13:25:50.10,
2021-05-25 13:26:20.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.25,
2021-05-25 13:26:23.24,
2021-05-25 13:26:24.25,
2021-05-25 13:26:24.25,
2021-05-25 13:26:24.25,
2021-05-25 09:33:50.07,
2021-05-26 08:53:44.44,
2021-05-26 08:53:44.44,
2021-05-26 08:53:44.44,
2021-05-26 08:53:44.44,
2021-05-26 08:53:49.95,
2021-05-26 08:53:49.95,
2021-05-26 08:53:49.95,
2021-05-26 08:53:52.46,
2021-05-26 08:53:52.46,
2021-05-26 08:53:52.46,
2021-05-26 08:53:52.46,
2021-05-26 08:53:57.47,
2021-05-26 08:53:57.48,
2021-05-26 08:53:57.47,
2021-05-26 08:53:57.49,
2021-05-26 08:53:57.47,
2021-05-26 08:55:47.78,
2021-05-25 10:07:34.21,
2021-05-25 10:21:15.28,
2021-05-25 10:34:43.88,
2021-05-26 11:58:36.39,
2021-05-26 11:59:06.51,
2021-05-26 11:59:29.10,
2021-05-26 11:59:29.11,
2021-05-26 12:00:36.37,
2021-05-26 12:01:06.49,
2021-05-26 12:01:36.10,
2021-05-26 12:01:37.03,
2021-05-26 12:01:37.03,
2021-05-26 12:01:37.03
```

**Thank you.**

Comment: Do you want to plot it as a histogram e.g. counts of datetimes within 6 hour intervals? Do they need to be fixed? e.g. 00:00:00 - 05:59:59; 06:00:00-11:59:59 etc.

Comment: If the timestamps are of class `"POSIXt"`, just `cut(x, breaks = "6 hours")`.

Comment: Thank you @RuiBarradas. Your suggestion helped tremendously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the xts object in the Note at the end:

```
library(xts)
x6 <- to.hourly(x, k = 6); x6
##                     x.Open x.High x.Low x.Close
## 2021-05-25 13:26:24     68     88    51      67
## 2021-05-25 15:06:18      1     50     1      50
## 2021-05-26 12:01:37     69     98    69      98
```

To extract the close use `Cl` from quantmod:

```
library(quantmod)
Cl(x6)
##                     x.Close
## 2021-05-25 13:26:24      67
## 2021-05-25 15:06:18      50
## 2021-05-26 12:01:37      98
```

If rounded hours are needed then this uses xts `align.time`:

```
to.hourly(align.time(x, n = 6 * 3600), k = 6)
##                     align.time(x, n = 6 * 3600).Close
## 2021-05-25 14:00:00                                67
## 2021-05-25 20:00:00                                50
## 2021-05-26 14:00:00                                98
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "2021-05-25 14:56:45.19,
2021-05-25 14:56:47.50,
2021-05-25 14:56:48.28,
2021-05-25 14:56:49.42,
2021-05-25 14:57:01.64,
2021-05-25 14:57:19.46,
2021-05-25 14:57:21.87,
2021-05-25 14:57:22.65,
2021-05-25 14:57:23.79,
2021-05-25 15:04:46.01,
2021-05-25 15:04:46.38,
2021-05-25 15:04:51.21,
2021-05-25 15:04:51.58,
2021-05-25 14:57:53.83,
2021-05-25 14:57:57.40,
2021-05-25 14:57:58.17,
2021-05-25 14:57:59.31,
2021-05-25 14:58:01.65,
2021-05-25 14:58:29.34,
2021-05-25 14:58:31.66,
2021-05-25 14:58:32.17,
2021-05-25 14:58:32.76,
2021-05-25 14:58:33.88,
2021-05-25 14:59:01.66,
2021-05-25 14:59:03.93,
2021-05-25 14:59:06.11,
2021-05-25 14:59:06.86,
2021-05-25 14:59:07.99,
2021-05-25 14:59:31.67,
2021-05-25 14:59:40.04,
2021-05-25 14:59:41.94,
2021-05-25 15:00:14.97,
2021-05-25 14:59:38.03,
2021-05-25 14:59:40.80,
2021-05-25 15:00:01.67,
2021-05-25 15:00:11.98,
2021-05-25 15:00:15.74,
2021-05-25 15:00:31.67,
2021-05-25 15:00:46.91,
2021-05-25 15:00:50.11,
2021-05-25 15:01:01.68,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.09,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.09,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.21,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.21,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.21,
2021-05-25 15:01:10.21,
2021-05-25 15:06:17.58,
2021-05-25 15:06:18.61,
2021-05-25 15:06:18.98,
2021-05-25 13:25:50.14,
2021-05-25 13:25:50.14,
2021-05-25 13:25:50.15,
2021-05-25 13:25:50.15,
2021-05-25 13:25:50.10,
2021-05-25 13:26:20.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.23,
2021-05-25 13:26:21.25,
2021-05-25 13:26:23.24,
2021-05-25 13:26:24.25,
2021-05-25 13:26:24.25,
2021-05-25 13:26:24.25,
2021-05-25 09:33:50.07,
2021-05-26 08:53:44.44,
2021-05-26 08:53:44.44,
2021-05-26 08:53:44.44,
2021-05-26 08:53:44.44,
2021-05-26 08:53:49.95,
2021-05-26 08:53:49.95,
2021-05-26 08:53:49.95,
2021-05-26 08:53:52.46,
2021-05-26 08:53:52.46,
2021-05-26 08:53:52.46,
2021-05-26 08:53:52.46,
2021-05-26 08:53:57.47,
2021-05-26 08:53:57.48,
2021-05-26 08:53:57.47,
2021-05-26 08:53:57.49,
2021-05-26 08:53:57.47,
2021-05-26 08:55:47.78,
2021-05-25 10:07:34.21,
2021-05-25 10:21:15.28,
2021-05-25 10:34:43.88,
2021-05-26 11:58:36.39,
2021-05-26 11:59:06.51,
2021-05-26 11:59:29.10,
2021-05-26 11:59:29.11,
2021-05-26 12:00:36.37,
2021-05-26 12:01:06.49,
2021-05-26 12:01:36.10,
2021-05-26 12:01:37.03,
2021-05-26 12:01:37.03,
2021-05-26 12:01:37.03"

library(xts)
tt <- scan(text = Lines, sep = ",", what = "")
tt <- as.POSIXct(tt[tt != ""])
x <- xts(seq_along(tt), tt)
```